# Unactive links and not clickable elements in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, button, hyperlink, click

Sometimes I have problem when few elements on page are not clickable. For example if I hover on button clickable can be image on this button, but not a text.
I have the last version of Google Chrome and use Mac book on m2 architecture

I tried to delete Google Chrom and download it again